# Insert same value as the previous record witha value in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a pipe delimited excel file where the rows are in first column like this

1|1734|abms|....

|||...

|||...

|||...

2|2356|abms|....

|||...

|||...

|||...

3|4567|Ql|....

|||...

|||...

|||...

i am trying to relate the rows with a value in the first position to the following rows without a value in first position and have it like this

1|1734|abms|....

1|||...

1|||...

1|||...

2|2356|abms|....

2|||...

2|||...

2|||...

3|4567|Ql|....

3|||...

3|||...

3|||...

I was using a formula like `=IF(LEFT(B2,1)="|",LEFT(B1,1),LEFT(B2,1))` but that only takes care of the row immediately following the row with a value. Any help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're putting the formula in column C, put the first value in C1 first. In C2 and onwards, use:

```
=IF(LEFT(B2)="|",LEFT(C1,FIND("|",C1)-1)&B2,B2)
```

This will use the previous value you just formed, if the row starts with a `|`.